# Equivalent of Seven Archangels of Zorastrianism in Vedic Religion?

Tags: vedas, gods, vedic-gods, demi-god, devatas

Zorastrianism and Early Vedic religion ar every similar, scholars even opine that they were one religion and got split into two, or one originated from the other.

Now in Zorastrianism there are seven Archangels called [Amesha Spenta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amesha_Spenta) meaning Holy Immortals.

> Amesha Spenta in the Gathas
> Gathic name - Approximate meaning
>
> 1. Spəṇta Mainyu -  Holy/Creative Spirit/Mentality
> 2. [Vohu] Manah  -  [Good] Purpose
> 3. Aša [Vahišta]  -  [Best] Truth / Righteousness
> 4. Xšaθra [Vairya]  -  [Desirable] Dominion
> 5. [Spənta] Armaiti  -  [Holy] Devotion
> 6. Haurvatāt  -  Wholeness
> 7. Amərətāt  -  Immortality

---

### Given that Zorastrianism is highly similar to early Vedic religion, who are the equivalent of Seven Archangels of Zorastrianism in Vedic Religion?

Comment: Ever heard about the Saptrishis?

Comment: @Just_Do_It  Interesting, very interesting. Did you say it because of Vahista? But are Saptarishis mentioned in Vedas?

Comment: Yes, check this on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saptarishi